# No support to -finline-functions in clang 3.5?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, inline

I am using clang 3.5 as distributed by them. I'm using the following command lines to install it in my travis vm:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://llvm.org/apt/precise/ llvm-toolchain-precise-3.5 main'
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://llvm.org/apt/precise/ llvm-toolchain-precise-3.5 main'
```

When I run my test build with optimizations turned on, I get this error:

```
clang: error: optimization flag '-finline-functions' is not supported
  "clang++" -c -x c++ -std=c++1y -Werror -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -Werror -pthread -fPIC -std=c++1y -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK -DNDEBUG -I"." -I"gamgee" -I"lib/htslib" -o "test/bin/run.test/clang-linux-3.5.0/release/threading-multi/sam_builder_test.o" "test/sam_builder_test.cpp"
```

I don't get the same error on my mac which runs the older 3.4 version of clang.

Has clang cut support to -finline-functions in 3.5? Is this something specific about this package build? How should one substitute the -finline-functions option for optimized builds with clang-3.5+?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See this commit: http://llvm.org/klaus/clang/commit/6590426aeb5275ec33dac2877f9349bbbb2d4b2e/#0-L-571

Previously, that flag was ignored and the user was not notified. Now the user is notified that it is ignored. You shouldn't have seen any difference in the code generation with or without that flag.

It should only be a warning, but you've upgraded it to an error with `-Werror`.

Comment: Can you share or point in the right direction why is it being ignored? Is it osx only or there must be a precondition for it to not be ignored?

Comment: I have no idea.